# How to Use Omniauth after the Authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, google-plus, linkedin-api, omniauth

Im developing and application that will need constant updates from users that will be gathered from their social networks (twitter, facebook, linkedin and g+), but omniauth just allows me to get this data on the authentication.

I need to get them after (with a delayed_job). I could manage to do so on facebook using Koala, but I don't really know how to do it for the other networks...

What I need to activate omniauth outside the authentication process?

Comment: Just search for the name of those networks followed by "gem". You have the Koala gem for Facebook, the Twitter gem for Twitter and so on. You can also check the [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/api_clients) to look for other gems.

Comment: @Ashitaka, Vladston gave me a right but obvious answer. Im looking for gems to avoid coding remote requests. So... please post your advice as an answer that Ill mark it as correct! Very usefull..

Answer (score 0):

You should use OmniAuth to authenticate user. Also you now have their token. Just use it to make API calls required for your task. Don't forget to have all privileges needed.